# ScrollViews will not resize

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have struggled with this and maybe I am not understanding how scrollviews work. I am trying to calculate the height automatically for 'self.description' however nothing I do seems to work. I have changed values from the scrollviewframe even tried changing the values using frame.size.height. however it still does not calculate the height. Am i missing something?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    if (self) {

        CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 460, 590);
        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.scrollView];


        [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

        scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
        scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;

        self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 67.0, 290, 50)];
        self.label.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
        self.label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33.0f/255.0f green:74.0f/255.0f blue:146.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [scrollView addSubview:self.label];

        //[self.contentView addSubview:self.label];

        self.description = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 380.0, 300, 9999)];
        self.description.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:15];
        self.description.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.description.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
        self.description.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.description.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        self.description.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [scrollView addSubview:self.description];
        //[self.contentView addSubview:self.description];


        self.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 130, 280, 228)];
        self.image.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [scrollView addSubview:self.image];
        //[self.contentView addSubview:self.image];

        float hgt=0; for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) hgt+=view.frame.size.height;
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width,hgt)];


        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to resize scrollview or the content size of the scroll?

If you like to resize scrollview, the self.contentView aren't resized and if it is not bigger or equal to scrollview, probably it's your issue.

Comment: I'm trying to resize the self.description subview. The content size

Comment: And you want to resize based in text length? and then, resize the scrollview, right?

Comment: Exactly what I want to do. I've tried so many different things to no avail.

Comment: Okay, i hope help with this:

`CGSize expectedLabelSize = [ownString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:fontSize] constrainedToSize:maxSize];`

maxSize are defined how max size label can grown, expectedLabelSize is the size results of your string or text within self.description.

Comment: I am a newbie so I have no idea how I am to use this....Where exactly do I put this?

Comment: Sorry, this code return size of the label, perhaps isn't 100% accurate, but this help you.

`self.description.frame=CGRectMake(origin.x,origin.y,widthDescription,maxSize.height);`

Put next to initialization.

Comment: self.description = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 380.0, 300, 9999)]; 
            self.description.frame=CGRectMake(origin.x,origin.y,widthDescription,maxSize.height); 

returns an unidentified 'origin'

Comment: Is the origin what you define for this view.

Answer (score 0):

```
float contentHeight = 0;

contentHeight = yourLastSubview.frame.origin.x + yourLastSubview.frame.size.height;

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width,contentHeight)];

//yourLastSubview is for example your self.description, because self.description' origin.y is the largest (380)
```

If your `scrollView.frame.size.height` is bigger than `contentHeight`, your `scrollView` won't scroll. For example if your `scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);` and your `contentHeight` is 400 scrollView won't scroll, but if `contentHeight = 500;` it will.

If you want to enable bouncing your scrollView when the contentHeight is smaller than your scrollView Height use this: `scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;`

Comment: No luck, Scrolling isn't the problem, Its the resizing of the self.description isn't being done.